# Accessing a variable declared in fla from document class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

On the stage I have a movieclip by the name of `rect_mc`. Inside it have have a MovieClip `square_mc`.

In the time line that I get when I double click on `rect_mc` (timeline of `rect_mc`) I have written the following code

```
var width1:Number;
width1 = sqaure_mc.width;
```

How can I access `width1` from the document class?

The thing that I want to is access the variable declared (`width1`) in the timeline
of `rect_mc`. Just for the sake of a example only I choose the width of MovieClip.

My doubt is how can access a variable declared inside the timeline of `rect_mc` from 
the document class. It could be any variable.

My document class is:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip

    public class Test extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            trace(rect_mc.width1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was my previous answer not alright..?

Comment: Hi Marty. Your answer was correct if what I wanted was just to access a property of the MovieClip. But my need was to access a variable declared in the timeline of a movieclip on stage and access it from the document class. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: If the previous question was the wrong one you should consider deleting it. As it stands now you have two questions which on the surface looks the same, but in reality one of the questions contains everything from the other plus some additional bits. Most likely the other question is no longer needed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I absolute not recommend using variables in the timeline, it is a very bad practice. In your case you could do something like this:

1. In the timeline of rect_mc: (call the function **init** in the document class and pass the width)

   MovieClip(parent).init(sqaure_mc.width);
2. In your document class:

   package 
       {

   ```
       import flash.display.MovieClip;

       public class Test extends MovieClip
       {
           public function Test()
           {

           }
           public function init(width1:Number):void
           {
               trace(width1);
           }
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: Downvote because this isn't so much "bad practice" as it is "not right for your project." Some of us can't work with hundreds of thousands of variables lumped in a document class, due to our particular project anatomy.